# Unable to convert .ts file with the mime type video/MP2T to .mp4

Tags: video, video-conversion, video-streaming, mp4

I want to play a bunch of `.ts` files. Most websites mention that users can usually play these files directly in vlc but I couldn't. There was no error. It is just that the file would not open at all. VLC will just keep showing a black screen. I tried a few other media player and none of them worked.

I then tried to convert `.ts` file to `.mp4` using Movavi video converter but it gave me an error about something being wrong with the file. The file is from a live streaming website so I don't think there is anything wrong with it.

Could anyone please tell me how can I successfully view or convert those files?

Comment: If neither VLC nor converters can open it, how can you be so sure there's nothing wrong with it?

Comment: Do the files incorporate Digital Rights Management?